# Volusion Template Issue "Add to cart to see price"

Tags: css, templates, volusion

On my Volusion store, when I use "Add to cart to see price" I've got a real problem with overflow and placement of the text. 
[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TISaV.jpg)

I've dug through the template HTML and CSS files and can't find where the code is to display this. I can't even find the correct file. Once I find it, I can copy the code from another template if necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the following CSS code that was placed in your template.css file it will be positioned correctly.

```
#MainForm .move_adc {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 6px;
}
```